# Visual Composer integration

Tags: shortcode, the-content

I've installed Visual Composer on my own template.
The thing is that is not rendering all it's shortcodes.

```
<?php  $post = get_post( $post->ID );
echo $post->post_content; ?>
```

Is that code wrong? Am I missing some includes or didn't run some functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved:

I had to `do_shortcode` to `post_content`.

Comment: Please accept your answer so that this question can be marked as resolved.  Thanks.

Comment: Also simple solution: Replace "<?php echo $post->post_content; ?>" with "<?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); ?>"